# canvas.toBlob not working with iPhone image upload

Tags: reactjs, iphone, canvas, blob

I've been working on an application in React that has cropping feature. The code should turn image into canvas and then canvas toBlob so I can use that base64 string later in code. Everything is fine and is working as it should on my android phone, on my computer and different browsers. The only issue is with iPhones. Only when uploading from iPhone with actual size selected do I get null value from canvas.toBlob(). When I upload image and select large instead of actual size, the code runs normally. Here is the code:

```
const getCroppedImg = (image: any, crop: Crop) => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
        const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
        canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio * scaleX;
        canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio * scaleY;

        if(ctx == null){
            return;
        }
    
        ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
    
        ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          crop.x * scaleX,
          crop.y * scaleY,
          crop.width * scaleX,
          crop.height * scaleY,
          0,
          0,
          crop.width * scaleX,
          crop.height * scaleY
        );
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          canvas.toBlob(
            (blob) => {
              if (!blob) {
                reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
                console.error('Canvas is empty');
                alert("Canvas is emtpy")
                return;
              }
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
              reader.onloadend = function(){
                if(reader.result != null && typeof(reader.result) === 'string'){
                    const base64data:string = reader.result
                    resolve(base64data);
                }
              }
              
            },
            'image/jpeg',
            0.5
          );
        });
    }
```

The image size doesnt matter, I uploaded larger filesizes from computer and it works and also i made 6000 x 6000 pixel image that also uploaded fine from my computer. I am really baffeled and don't know where to start. I have seen people complain about toBlob on Safari, but toBlob works fine if Actual Size is not selected. Also, same thing happens on chrome on iPhone.

Any lead would be helpful, because I ran out of ideas. I think that posting other code will just bloat this post, but if anyone needs to know what else is happening in the app I will gladly post that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [browser limitations for toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#browser_compatibility).

Safari is listed as supporting it since 2017 and iOS 11, but still does not support "quality".  It appears you are using that parameter in some form with "imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'".

If it ends up you are having a browser support issue, one solution is to polyfill it with something like blueimp-canvas-to-blob.  Or obviously just do not use the parameter in question.